# When using generic in the dbset of the entity framework at Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity, entity-framework-migrations

I made this change, before it was like this

```
    public DbSet<Pessoa> Pessoas { get; set; }
```

Now it's this way

```
class ContextData<T> : DbContext where T : class
{
    public DbSet<T> Dbset { get; set; }

    public ContextData() : base("name=Connection")
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {            

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PessoaMapping());                          

        }
}
```

So now I do not know what I do in class migrations

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<local.blogapi.Context.ContextData
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(local.blogapi.Context.ContextData context)
    {

    }
}
```

I know it's going to make a mistake. I do not know how to get the entities or if there is any specific command at the time of doing the migration, or if I pass some interface, such as IEntity

Comment: Are you trying to make a context of every table? If so, why? I wouldnt recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

you're probably wrong.

A context is a group of dbset (dbsets represent sql tables), read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj729737%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

I think that you don't need one context for every table in your db.
Use of more contexts may make sense if you want to separate dbsets that have different logic (based on the schema for example, or to separate read / write tables)

Comment: I understand! I read about the context but actually I was trying create dbset automatic, but i see this is not possible

Comment: @WallaceFerreira exactly. i suggest you also this reference http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/ to learn entity framework